# Are Blessing Spirits mutants as well?

Tags: from-the-new-world

When Shun became a Karmic Demon, he realized that his powers were always leaking and affecting the world around them, mutating animals such as sea slugs into [Minoshiros](http://shinsekaiyori.wikia.com/wiki/False_Minoshiro#Forest_Minoshiro).

Considering that the sign that a child has gained their powers is the presence of a Blessing Spirit, this would be an indication that their powers are already leaking at this point.

So does this mean the Blessing Spirit is just another mutant? If so, what creature was originally a basis, and did they all end up looking the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blessing Spirits aren't *actually* a physical thing. Rather, the agglomeration of bizarre phenomena that the people in the show describe as a "Blessing Spirit" is simply a subconscious/unconscious manifestation of the child's latent powers. To the uninformed observer, it *looks* like what we might call a "poltergeist" - but as we know from the narrative, the real explanation doesn't entail a separate physical being causing the strange phenomena.

I don't know why they refer to it as though it were a physical being. Perhaps it's a fiction the adults maintain to keep the children from understanding the true nature of their powers and the damage that power leakage can cause? (Keep in mind that the students are never taught in school how karma demons *really* originate.)